C# interface method that can accept a number of parameters and various data types dynamically
I have an IRepository interface with several methods.
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>?> GetAllAsync();    
    Task<int> InsertAsync(T obj);
    Task<int> UpdateAsync(T obj);
    Task<int> DeleteAsync(T entity);
}

I want to add a method to retrieve data based on Id or key . The problem is that some data has more than one key, it could be two keys, three keys and so on, and the data type for each data can be different. Is there a solution in C# so that the parameters of a method can be flexible in terms of amount and data type?
Previously I tried using TKey on the method and overloading the method. I don't think this is a good solution.
public T GetById<TKey>(TKey key);
public T GetById<TKey1, Tkey2>(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2);
public T GetById<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3>(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2, TKey3 key3);

Note: I use ADO.NET.
Are there any other ideas or solutions? Thank you for your help.

In case of multiple keys, you could pass them as single parameter of type ValueTuple like repository.GetById((key1, key2, key3)).`

Pass something like a List, ArrayList...

If I use ValueTuple, I need to overload methods that are not necessarily used in derived classes, is that correct?

Just take one TKey, and the caller can pass in a tuple if they want to use multiple keys. What do you mean by "overload methods that are not necessarily used in derived classes"? Please show an example.

Maybe params object[] keyComponents, similar to how EF does it, or better still, don't try to force this into a generic interface if each entity type is handled differently.

Just so it is off the table: Are you wrapping Entity Framework (Core) in your spin of a Repository-Pattern?

Also, trying to give generic types to the overloads is largely useless, it achieves nothing other than potentially preventing boxing of value types. The implementation won't be able to do anything beyond handle the values as object anyway, and the the consumer will be able to pass anything.

@Sweeper, I think you are right. I didn't think that a TKey was an object. I think that one TKey represents one data type. So if I need two or three data types I need to create an overload method like my example public T GetById<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3>(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2, TKey3 key3);

@BeerBaron, I don't think Arraylist is good for performance but it's also good to try. Thanks

Nobody uses ArrayList.  Mind the Remarks => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-8.0#remarks

I'd say if you have Composite Keys, you'd want a "CompositeKey" abstraction type for TKey.

Avoid Task<IEnumerable<T>>. Use IAsyncEnumerable<T> instead. As for a more drastic recommendation... I'd suggest going with EFCore and completely dropping your custom repository abstraction: it never scales well and creates a huge maintenance problem in all codebases I've ever worked with.

@julealgon, Thank you for the information about IAsyncEnumerable and your suggestions. I just found out that there is a new syntax IAsyncEnumerable. Regarding EFCore, I'm not familiar with it, so for now I'm using ADO.NET because I'm running out of time. And from the information I have read, EFCore is not good for large data, ADO.NET performance is better than EFCore, and EFCore is difficult to use for complex database queries.

@julealgon, Regarding abstraction, previously I thought not to use abstraction, so I had to declare the class repository that I used in the service class. When I saw the Unit of Work pattern and I was interested because it seemed to be easier. Can you explain in general the constraints of class abstraction, so that it can be taken into consideration by me. Thank You

From an interface perspective, it's relatively simple to add a composite key type for this purpose.
public interface IKeyedRepository<TKey, TValue> : IRepository<TValue>
    where TValue : class
{
    public TValue GetById(TKey key);
}

Note: I'm applying the interface segregation principle here. Using a separate interface means we don't require IRepository<> consumers to know about the key type unless they need it, while still providing a degree of type safety to those who do. You're certainly welcome to add TKey to the IRepository<> interface itself, if that suits your needs better.
In cases where the Key is comprised of multiple values, you could make it a class, record, or named Tuple.
public record PetKey(string PetName, int OwnerId);
public class PetRepository : IKeyedRepository<PetKey, Pet> {...}
// OR //
public class PetRepository : IKeyedRepository<(string PetName, int OwnerId), Pet> {...}

You might even decide to use a class when there's only one value to the key, just to avoid primitive obsession and give you a chance to enforce prior validation of the key values. But that's probably overkill.
The hard part may come in the implementation. Presumably one of the benefits you're getting from a unified, generic interface is that your implementations are able to reuse code. Without knowing what your current implementation looks like, it's hard to say how best to implement GetByKey in a way that allows maximum code reuse.

A simple way would probably be:
public T GetById(IEnumerable<TKey> keys)

then have some sort of implementation.
Or maybe something like this:
public T GetById(IEnumerable<TKey> keys, Func<T, TKey> keySelector);

Then implement like:
public T GetById(IEnumerable<TKey> keys, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            var entity = _db.Entity.SingleOrDefault(e => keySelector(e).Equals(key));
            if (entity != null)
            {
                return entity;
            }
        }

        // Return null if no item is found
        return null;
    } }


The point of the question is to have different key types.

keySelector(e) won't be translatable to SQL. Even if it were, you're trying to query an item per key, whereas OP wants to use a composite key to query as ingle item.
